# Saving Window Configurations in Emacs

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

I'm wondering if there's a way to save window configurations across emacs sessions.  I know desktop-save is fantastic for preserving buffers and whatnot and the emacs manual demonstrates storing a window configuration into a register but this doesn't persist across sessions.

Of course this doesn't seem like it would be too hard to implement myself...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

EmacsWiki is a great resource: [EmacsWiki: Session Management](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SessionManagement)

Looks like [Windows Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WindowsMode), or more specifically revive.el, is what you want.

Answer (score 5):

A lot has changed since 2008, and `desktop-save-mode` now also restores frames across sessions. Emacs 24.4 and higher.

Comment: It restores "frames" (which are windows to everybody but emacs users), not "windows" (which are those internal terminal-split things).