# Load Emacs File and Create Window Arrangement Upon Load

Tags: emacs, startup

I am wondering if and how it is possible to do the following things in Emacs:

1. Load a certain file whenever Emacs is opened. In particular, it is a .ORG file located in user's home directory.
2. Create a certain arrangement of windows within that Emacs frame. The frame is open as a GUI, if that matters. For example, it could be two vertical windows with one of them in-turn split into three smaller windows.

Comment: For point 2, do `desktop-save` and `desktop-read` do what you want? (See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/392314/113848))

Comment: Here is a link to an example of how to achieve something very similar to what you are looking for:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26967/open-several-files-in-a-specifc-layout-with-a-shortcut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat inelegant solution, but you could just have your init file run the exact same commands that you would use to manually achieve your setup (use `C-h f` to help look up any keyboard shortcuts whose command names you don't know).

To open a file, you can use the command `find-file` (the command run by `C-x f`). You can use `split-window-right` and `split-window-below` (`C-x 2` and `C-x 3`, respectively) to split your window. (It should be noted that there is a more general `split-window` command, but I'm avoiding it here since I am just replicating what Emacs would do if we set everything up manually.) The command `other-window` (`C-x o`) changes windows within a frame - note that this function requires an input argument (the number of windows to go over) when not used interactively.

You could obtain a setup similar to what you were asking about (org file on left, 3 horizontal splits on right, all separate empty buffers) with the following:

```
(find-file "ABSOLUTE-PATH-TO-FILE.org")
(split-window-right)
(other-window 1)
(split-window-below)
(switch-to-buffer "Fresh-Buffer-1")
(other-window 1)
(split-window-below)
(switch-to-buffer "Fresh-Buffer-2")
(other-window 1)
(switch-to-buffer "Fresh-Buffer-3")
(balance-windows)
(other-window 1)
```

You may also want to use the functions `set-frame-height` and/or `set-frame-width` to give yourself an appropriately sized frame (example usage `(set-frame-width (selected-frame) 120)`). Additionally, I'd recommend putting this at the end of your init file so that the modes of the buffers you are creating can't interfere with any of your other init functions.

Comment: Thanks. `balance-windows` has been quite a find for me in recent days :)